# C++ -static Flag makes executable too big

Tags: c++, file, static, linker, size

Im using Mingw compiler on windows environment. When I compile a hello world program with iostream with this flags:`g++ hello.cpp -static -s` output is 967 kb. When I use `g++ hello.cpp -s` output is 16 kb but it gives libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing error on other computers. How can I build it with acceptable file size?

Comment: What you will likely find is that the actual library `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` will be of a much greater size than both your binaries. So distributing you executable with alongside the mingw shared library will actually increase the total size. This is with the exception that you have a large number of mingw using shared libraries on a particular system. Also Why is 967kb not acceptable?? that is less than 1mb??? surely with today's harware that is an trivial amount of storage??

Comment: From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) of GCC the `-static` keyword prevents linking with the shared libraries. Which means the library will be statically linked(the libraries become part of your program) with your program leading to an increase in size.

Comment: @silvergasp 967KB executable is not acceptable because core Windows DLLs have already implement a printf version. So anything bigger that 30KB is unacceptable. And of course 2-4KB is ok. There is some padding in code/data/relloc sections so you cannot go < 1KB. Now, we are talking about sensible sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try stripping the debug information from your executable using [strip](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html) to reduce the size somewhat but that will make debugging it directly somewhat difficult.